# Implementation of sidekiq timeout in a rails worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a rails worker which fetches me data from a third party website. I have recently upgraded to sidekiq pro. How to implement my worker such that it stops fetching data from third party website after sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a timeout on the network request directly.  Sidekiq can't time out your job.  I documented the problem and some solutions on my blog here.

http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/